# Javascript / jQuery - convert special html characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `pre` element with some html code in it.
the code has special characters in it, like `&lt;`, so it doesn't break the page.

Then I have a javascript function that gets the contents of this pre element, highlights it (with codemirror), and replaces the element contents with the highlighted text.

I'm using `$("pre").append(...);` to do this.
The problem is that after the highlighting, on the screen I see `&lt;` instead of `<`.
How can I convert these characters back to html?

Comment: what method is used for fetching the html?

Comment: the contents of the initial pre ? I do this with `var content = code.html();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using the .text() method to grab the code from the pre.  This way you are't giving the encoded symbols to the code highlighter.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know what happens (and why it happens) to your html, but you can use jQuerys `.text()` and `.html()` to decode/encode html entitiys like:

HTML

```
<div id="test">&lt;&lt;</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var t = $('#test');
t.html(t.text()); // will print "<<"
```

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/fphw3

**update**

Since you mentioned that you use `.html()` to read the value of your element, a call to `.text()` instead should solve your issue.