# Accents and HTML entities in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I've got a JSON file (pulled in from an API) where I'm doing some comparisons. I fetch the content of the JSON file and put it on some buttons (as button text). I then do a comparison test for equality between the button text and text in the JSON file.

This works in 99% of my use cases however:

Some words in my JSON file have accents on them (either é or so on). When I try and do a comparison in jQuery, even though I'm using the:

```
   $(this).html()
```

for my button text, the equality test fails. The word in the JSON File might read:

```
   Fr&eacute;d&eacute;ric Auguste Bartholdi
```

but on my button it reads:

```
    Frédéric Auguste Bartholdi
```

I thought if I did a comparison test such as:

```
    if($(this).html() === jsonFile[0])){...}
```

that would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to do it. For clarity (this) refers to my button and I can't really do much about the JSON file - can't be changed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18160397/2019247). You need to replace the accented characters with their english equivalents before comparing.

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330345/javascript-jquery-convert-special-html-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It easy:

```
function html_entities(str){
    return $('<textarea />').html(str).text();
}
$('div').text(html_entities("Fr&eacute;d&eacute;ric Auguste Bartholdi"));
```

See at: https://jsfiddle.net/kilotonna/yy46na0g/

Thanks for: [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $(this).html() use $(this).text(). Because .html() - will returns the html format of those unicodes.

Answer (score 0):

you should try  `$(this).text()` instead of    `$(this).html()`